# What's the relationship between scaleX and anchorPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to flip a sprite horizontally i.e.

```
sprite.scaleX = -1;
```

What I notice is that the sprite is flipped around its bottom left corner. However since I don't want to mess up my positioning of the sprite (I'd like the sprite to stay in the original place), so I tried to set its anchor point to (1,0)

```
sprite.anchorPoint = ccp(1,0);
```

My reasoning is this:

Since the sprite should be flipped around the `anchorPoint`, if I set the `anchorPoint` to its bottom right corner then that corner will then become the 'left bottom' corner of the changed sprite; and I should be able to move the sprite using that new `anchorPoint` just as I do with a normal sprite of `anchorPoint (0,0)`.

However apparently it's not working as I expected. What am I missing?

**Edit**

What I really want to do is to flip a sprite and then be able to control its position via the left bottom corner - well the left bottom corner of the sprite that I see. I don't think I fully understand how scaleX = -1 is applied relating to the anchorPoint. If somebody can explain to me the concepts behind these parameters then that will greatly help me.

Comment: why don't you use sprite.flipX?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I did try that, but to no effect. I'm guessing that the sprite contains several nodes and flipX only deals with individual texture

Comment: you can also use 0,0 anchor point and then just add contentSize.width to position.x to get the same effect (origin at lower right corner)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D that would mean breaking some of my existing implementations that assume the sprite is anchored at (0,0) though; in other words, I can't write general functions that deal with such situations.

Answer (score 0):

I have to correct myself on making the assertion that setting anchorPoint doesn't help. In fact, setting anchorPoint to (1,0) is exactly the solution to the problem, only that somehow some bug prevented me from recognizing it in my test.